# In javascript: Changing "src" for a newly created script-element doesn't work..?

Tags: javascript, src

I'm *very* new to javascript, but I've managed to stitch the following together from different code-snippets, and forum-posts:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://service.somewebsite.com/?api-key=4P1k3y5R4w50m3";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(s);
```

However - it doesn't work.

The source-attribute is obviously not real (the service asked me to not share the API-key), but pasting the actual one into a browser, I get the excact script I want - with the right callback and everything.

I find it odd that this code doesn't work since the very similar

```
var i = document.createElement("img");
i.src = "http://i.imgur.com/TsCGbsy.jpg";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(i);
```

...executes just fine, when it takes its place. Is there something I don't know about changing the source of a script-element, or is there something else I've overlooked?

On a side note: I want to end up having "s.src" rely on some variables like the method, the api-key etc. (which is why I define it like this). If anyone has some other elegant solution  to this, I'd be thankful as well. Any tips on syntax etc. are also very welcome.

Thanks in advance for any sort of help on this!

EDIT: I maybe should have mentioned that I'm trying to execute code from a source that consists of a JSON-object wrapped in a callback-function. The link itself works fine, and the function is executed properly when using

```
<script src = "http://service.somewebsite.com/?api-key=
k3y&callback=myFunction">
</script>
```

I'm basically attempting to do the same thing, only with (src) being stitched together from a string and one or more variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Please be more specific.

Comment: [Cross domain](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=cross+domain+scripting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-au:official&client=firefox-a&safe=active) issue?

Comment: Does the `<body>` already exist in the DOM when that code is executed?

Comment: @RobG: Not for including `<script>` elements - that's why they're used for JSONP

Comment: Is the string you use to set `s.src` properly encoded? Testing by pasting into browser masks URL encoding issues sometimes

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I wish I could be more specific, but the JSON-callback-function asociated with my link, simply isn't executed. The function itself works fine, when doing this:

<script src = http://service.somewebsite.com/?api-key=4P1k3y5R4w50m3></script>

...And as far as I understand, this is basically also what I'm attempting to do with the code above - only with (src) being dependant on one or more variables. Or am I mistaking?

Answer (score 1):

Try using setAttribute:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s.setAttribute("src", "http://service.somewebsite.com/?api-key=4P1k3y5R4w50m3");
```

Comment: That's very likely the problem, `src` is not exposed as a DOM node property